# share sessions among asp.net 4.6.2 and asp.net core in SQL Server

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, session-state

We have a very long history intranet application developed with classic asp in the beginning. Then we converted some in vb.net. So we have two projects in this application(classic asp and asp.net).
  Now, we decided to use latest asp.net core to continue converting old pages. However, we are now met a road block - **Share sessions between asp.net and asp.net core using SQL database**. We had successfully share sessions between asp.net and MVC 5 in SQL Server and it was not difficult. Now, asp.net core changed its table structure for session storing. 
  Is there a way to share sessions between asp.net and asp.net core? Someone suggested to use Shim(?) I don't know really what this is. Will Shim work or is there better way to achieve this? Thank you so much in advance for reading.